# getInt Function Doesn't Return Anything

Tags: java, config, minecraft

I am currently trying to making a custom rules plugin (for minecraft) and I am trying to see if the player has something activated which I stored in the config file. It is in the listener class (which calls the config from the main). Here is my code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEvent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

    Player player = e.getPlayer();


    if (config.getInt("EditingLine." + player.getName().toLowerCase()) == 1) {
        int line = 0;
        try {
            line = Integer.parseInt(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception b) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid Number.");
            config.set("EditingLine." + player.getName().toLowerCase(), 0);
        }

        if (!(line == 0)) {
            config.set("EditingLine." + player.getName().toLowerCase(), 0);
            config.set("EditingText." + player.getName().toLowerCase(), 1);
            e.setCancelled(true);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Custom Rules" + ChatColor.GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Enter the text you would now like on that line.");
        }
    }

}
```

The, config.getInt() function in the if then statement currently returns nothing. This may be happening because the config in the Listener Class is actually calling a custom made config, called 'playerdata.yml' and not the actual 'config.yml'. If there is any easier way to write this script, also let me know. I'm trying to make this as simple as I can.

Comment: What type is config? What's the signature of `getInt()`?

Comment: @Paul Hicks The config creates a FileConfiguration and then sets that to the 'playerdata.yml' config that was created in the main class.

Comment: A method can't "return nothing" unless it's `void`, in which case your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I tried using player.sendMessage(" " + config.getInt('path') when the onEvent was called, and nothing was sent.

Comment: That tells me that `sendMessage` didn't send anything, not that `getInt` didn't return anything. Try logging the return value instead of sending it as a message.

Comment: @PaulHicks I logged the return value and an error appeared.  (I could not fit the error message so I screenshot it: https://i.imgur.com/ZKa71ai.png)

Comment: Hard to tell from that exception, but it looks like your event isn't triggering your handler. The problem may well be outside of this code.

Comment: @PaulHicks Would it be because the config file referenced is a .yml file that was created by myself and isn't the 'config.yml' file? If it is, I could merge the two.

Comment: No idea. The exception doesn't have enough detail. Debugging is probably required, or at least sufficient simplification of the code, allowing you to eliminate all the false negatives until you get to the root cause.

Comment: @PaulHicks I managed to fix the problem by merging the two configurations together. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -3):

The answer has been solved by merging my two configuration files together.